# Issues with Formatting: Converting JSON into CSV using multiple JSON objects embedded with in the main object

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am having some trouble with the formatting while converting the JSON object to CSV

My json file is a list of json objects they all share the same main keys names except Dict2 some may not have it, also Dict1 may or may not be of type dictionary and may also include other dictionaries. And the output would be a csv file of all these objects despite their parameters

My Json object is:

```
[{
        "Name": "NameOfObject1",
        "Number": "objectNumber1",
        "Dict1": {
            "Key1": "true",
            "Key2": "false",
            "Key3": {
                     "key1InK3": "Hello",
                     "key2InK3": "There",
}
        },
        "BooleanValue": false,
    },
{
        "Name": "NameOfObject2",
        "Number": "objectNumber2",
        "Dict1": {
            "Key1": "true",
            "Key2": "false",
            "Key3": "true"
        },
        "BooleanValue": false,
        "Dict2":{
            "otherKey1" : "this ",
            "otherKey2" : "is ",
            "otherKey3" : "a ",
            "otherKey4" : "test ",
            "otherKey5" : "haha ",
            "otherKey6" : "i ",
            "otherKey7" : "like ",
            "otherKey8" : "strawberry "
        }
    },
{
        "Name": "NameOfObject3",
        "Number": "objectNumber",
        "Dict1": "this is a string",
        "BooleanValue": false
    }
]
```

My output looks like this:

```
Name           Number        Dic1             Dic1 Values Dic1 Values Of dictionaries Inside Boolean Value Dic2          Dic2 Values   
         
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1                                                                 FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key1             TRUE                                           FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key2                                                            FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key2             key1InK2                                       FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key2             key1InK2    Hello                              FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key2             key2InK2                                       FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key2             key2InK2    There                              FALSE                                     
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                              TRUE                                                                         
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key3                                                            FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key3             key1InK3                                       FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key3             key1InK3    Good                               FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key3             key2InK3                                       FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key3             key2InK3    Morining                           FALSE                                     
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2 Key1             TRUE                                           TRUE                                      
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2 Key2             FALSE                                          TRUE                                      
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2 Key3             TRUE                                           TRUE                                      
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey1     This          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey2     is            
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey3     a             
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey4     test          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey5     haha          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey6     i             
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey7     like          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey8     strawberry    
NameOfObject3 objectNumber3 This is a String                                                FALSE
```

and I want it to look like this: Notice how the last 2 Columns got shifted up and the last 3 rows of object 2 got deleted. also notice how all the rows where the Dic1 values were empty in Object 2 are also removed

```
Name           Number        Dic1             Dic1 Values Dic1 Values Of dictionaries Inside Boolean Value Dic2          Dic2 Values   

NameOfObject1 objectNumber1                                                                 FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key1             TRUE                                           FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key2             key1InK2    Hello                              FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key2             key2InK2    There                              FALSE                                     
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                              TRUE                                                                         
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key3             key1InK3    Good                               FALSE                                     
NameOfObject1 objectNumber1 Key3             key2InK3    Morining                           FALSE                                     
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                  TRUE                                           TRUE                                      
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2 Key1             TRUE                                           TRUE          otherKey1     this          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2 Key2             FALSE                                          TRUE          otherKey2     is            
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2 Key3             TRUE                                           TRUE          otherKey3     a             
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey4     test          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey5     haha          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey6     i             
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey7     like          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey8     strawberry    
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey      i             
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey7     like          
NameOfObject2 objectNumber2                                                                 TRUE          otherKey8     strawberry    
NameOfObject3 objectNumber3 This is a String                                                FALSE
```

I have no idea how to do that, I don't see the logic behind it. I don't want to rewrite the whole code.
The Code is too long to post here but here is the logic behind it

```
ListOfLines = []
Loop Through Dictionary keys file
    if key is dictionary:
          append a new line and recursively call the function
     else: (key is not dictionary)
          add the keys and values to a line
Formats all the lines and cleans up the list then writes to the output file
```

You see at the if statement, a new line is created so the dictionary output is always on the next line. This works fine when there is only 1 dictionary but with 2 dictionaries I get the output shown above, which isn't bad but isn't good either. I don't want to change the code unless it is absolutely necessary.

My train of thought is simply using python to move the group of cells up a few rows but I have no idea how to do that. Even if I knew I can't simply just move it up 3 rows as other files might have 5-7 keys in Dict1.

In conclusion, my question is:
How do I move a group of cells up using python based on this logic that I cannot think of a way to put into code?
Any help on this?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built on Corralien's answer and I got it to work how i wanted

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('file.json','r') as f:
    fileStuff = json.load(f)
for obj in fileStuff:
   jdata=json.dump(obj)
   data = json.loads(jdata)  # jdata is your JSON as string
   df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=0)

   # Extract dict columns
   dcols = [k for k, v in data.items() if isinstance(v, dict)]

   # Explode dict as DataFrame
   dfs = []
   for col in dcols:
       dd = (pd.json_normalize(df.pop(col)).squeeze()
            .rename_axis(col).rename(f'{col} Values')
            .reset_index())
       dfs.append(dd)

   # Create the final dataframe
   if len(dcols)>0: #concat throws an exception when it a basic json object
      df = df.merge(pd.concat(dfs, axis=1), how='cross')
   df.to_csv('out.csv', 'a',index=False)
```

After that you have a csv file with all the json objects. The file needs some cleaning but it really just dealing with basic pandas dataframes and depending on your situation

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `pd.json_normalize(..., max_level=0)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.loads(jdata)  # jdata is your JSON as string
df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=0)

# Extract dict columns
dcols = [k for k, v in data.items() if isinstance(v, dict)]

# Explode dict as DataFrame
dfs = []
for col in dcols:
    dd = (pd.json_normalize(df.pop(col)).squeeze()
            .rename_axis(col).rename(f'{col} Values')
            .reset_index())
    dfs.append(dd)

# Create the final dataframe
out = df.merge(pd.concat(dfs, axis=1), how='cross')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
           Name        Number  BooleanValue Dict1 Dict1 Values      Dict2 Dict2 Values
0  NameOfObject  objectNumber         False  Key1         true  otherKey1        this 
1  NameOfObject  objectNumber         False  Key2        false  otherKey2          is 
2  NameOfObject  objectNumber         False  Key3         true  otherKey3           a 
3  NameOfObject  objectNumber         False   NaN          NaN  otherKey4        test 
4  NameOfObject  objectNumber         False   NaN          NaN  otherKey5        haha 
5  NameOfObject  objectNumber         False   NaN          NaN  otherKey6           i 
6  NameOfObject  objectNumber         False   NaN          NaN  otherKey7        like 
7  NameOfObject  objectNumber         False   NaN          NaN  otherKey8  strawberry 

>>> df
           Name        Number                                              Dict1  BooleanValue                                              Dict2
0  NameOfObject  objectNumber  {'Key1': 'true', 'Key2': 'false', 'Key3': 'true'}         False  {'otherKey1': 'this ', 'otherKey2': 'is ', 'ot...
```

Input:

```
jdata = """
{
    "Name": "NameOfObject",
    "Number": "objectNumber",
    "Dict1": {
        "Key1": "true",
        "Key2": "false",
        "Key3": "true"
    },
    "BooleanValue": false,
    "Dict2":{
        "otherKey1" : "this ",
         "otherKey2" : "is ",
         "otherKey3" : "a ",
         "otherKey4" : "test ",
         "otherKey5" : "haha ",
         "otherKey6" : "i ",
         "otherKey7" : "like ",
         "otherKey8" : "strawberry "
    }
}
"""
```

Comment: Thanks but I guess I should have been more clear, my json file is a list of json objects they all share the same main keys names except Dict2 some may not have it, also Dict1 may or may not be of type dictionary and may also include other dictionaries. And the output would be a csv file of all these objects despite their parameters. while this method is 100x better than what i have, i don't think it would work for me

Comment: So please update your post with a simple sample like a real case, I will answer it tomorrow.

Comment: quick question, when a dict has size 1 like
`example:{"Key":"value"}`
`pd.json_normalize(df.pop(col)).squeeze().rename_axis(col).rename(f'{col} Values').reset_index()` 
doesnt work, it gives `
'str' object has no attribute 'rename_axis` 
so I removed all other functions and its just `
pd.json_normalize(df.pop(col))` 
and it returns a df with key as header and value as a row, I tried transposing it and it doesnt work, you know how i can make it to work?